# Copy and Paste values from a Row multiple times in a Column in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently working on a project on VBA that requires multiple manipulation on data.

So, the main idea  of this will be to get the data that I have on "Q1" and paste it 4 times on A (starting at the first blank cell), after that, take the data from "Q2" and do the same until there is no more data on the "Q" column. After there is no more data, the process should stop.

Later on I may need to modify the process, so the value gets pasted only 2 or 3 times instead of 4.

**Something like this:**

Column Q data:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: Can you give a little more details?

Comment: What happens when you run out of columns? The data you're copying is in column Q, and you're copying it across starting at column A.  That means you run out of columns at P, do you just keep going (overwriting what was originally in Q2)? Or start over on column A on the next row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do what you want:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Transpose_Multiplied()
    Dim Number_Of_Repetitions As Integer
    Dim Input_Column As String
    Dim Output_Column As String
    ' -----------------------------------------------------------
    ' These are the control variables ....
        Number_Of_Repetitions = 4
                 Input_Column = "Q"
                Output_Column = "A"
    ' -----------------------------------------------------------
    Dim WSht As Worksheet
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim LastACell As Long
    Dim i As Integer

    Set WSht = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    For Each Cell In WSht.Range(Input_Column & "2:" & Input_Column & WSht.Cells(WSht.Rows.Count, Input_Column).End(xlUp).Row)
        For i = 1 To Number_Of_Repetitions
            LastACell = WSht.Cells(WSht.Rows.Count, Output_Column).End(xlUp).Row
            If LastACell = 1 And WSht.Cells(LastACell, Output_Column).Value = vbNullString Then
                WSht.Cells(LastACell, Output_Column).Value = Cell.Value
            Else
                WSht.Cells(LastACell + 1, Output_Column).Value = Cell.Value
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

So, I open up my workbook and leave it open on the Worksheet where the data to be processed is. Then I run the macro from my PERSONAL.XLSB:

[image]